# Tuning Execute Immediate statements present in procedures

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlperformance

I wanted to tune a procedure which has number of dynamic SQL statements that are taking too much time to execute. I need help to tune those or some alternate solution.

Example:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE C1_LAN_GTT_1 NOLOGGING PARALLEL 4 AS 
SELECT /*+INDEX(C,CR_DECISION_M_CD1)*/ A.AGREEMENTID, 
       A.AGREEMENTNO, A.LESSEEID, A.PRODUCTFLAG, A.APP_FORMNO, A.AMTFIN
FROM   LEA_AGREEMENT_DTL A, CR_DECISION_M C
WHERE  A.AGREEMENTID = C.APPID
AND    A.STATUS = ''A''
AND    TRUNC(C.AUTHDATE) BETWEEN' || '''' || P_FROM_DATE || '''' ||
                       ' AND ' || '''' || P_TO_DATE || '''';
```

When I was checking procedure in debug mode in PLSQL Developer I found these dynamic statements taking too much time.

The query has no data still taking time to execute.

Comment: `TRUNC(C.AUTHDATE)` might be a problem. Is that column indexed or a partition key? And the date parameters should be properly formatted date literals, not what you have above.

Comment: By the way, why is the table named `C1_LAN_GTT_1` when it's not a GTT?

Comment: It is existed code before it might be GTT now they have changed

Comment: What you say is delay because of date filter.

Answer (score 1):

Without a lot more details such as the execution plan and full details of the tables, indexes and data volumes and distribution, I don't know what performance problems you are facing. However, I might start with something like this:

```
declare
    p_from_date date := date '2018-01-01';
    p_to_date   date := date '2018-02-01';

    myddl long := 'create table c1_lan_gtt_1 nologging parallel 4 as 
    select /*+index(c cr_decision_m_cd1)*/ a.agreementid, 
           a.agreementno, a.lesseeid, a.productflag, a.app_formno, a.amtfin
    from   lea_agreement_dtl a
           join cr_decision_m c on c.appid = a.agreementid
    where  a.status = ''A''
    and    c.authdate between date ''' || to_char(p_from_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') || '''' ||
                    ' and date '''     || to_char(p_to_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') || '''';
begin
    dbms_output.put_line(myddl);
end;
```

which generates

```
create table c1_lan_gtt_1 nologging parallel 4 as 
    select /*+index(c cr_decision_m_cd1)*/ a.agreementid, 
           a.agreementno, a.lesseeid, a.productflag, a.app_formno, a.amtfin
    from   lea_agreement_dtl a
           join cr_decision_m c on c.appid = a.agreementid
    where  a.status = 'A'
    and    trunc(c.authdate) between date '2018-01-01' and date '2018-02-01'
```

**Edit:** since index `CR_DECISION_M_CD1` is on `(APPID, TRUNC(AUTHDATE))` (from comments) I have restored the `trunc()` function even though logically it is not needed.

Comment: The problem means the reason behind this delay in execution, even there is no data for  this query. That's it. If you know any other way I can create table instead of this  to increase the performance of procedure.Please share

Comment: Does my version improve performance? It might, if `authdate` is indexed or is a partition key, which is why I asked.

Comment: I've just seen your comment on another answer - index `CR_DECISION_M_CD1` is on `(APPID, TRUNC(AUTHDATE))`. In that case you should retain the `trunc()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Check P_FROM_DATE and P_TO_DATE are bind variables [enter link description here](https://blogs.oracle.com/sql/improve-sql-query-performance-by-using-bind-variables)

Comment: Unfortunately this is DDL so bind variables are not allowed. I doubt it would improve performance even if they were, though, as the performance issue seems to be in the query that populates the table, not in parsing.

Answer (score -1):

New version of execute immediate statement using exists instead of join:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE C1_LAN_GTT_1 NOLOGGING PARALLEL 4 AS 
SELECT A.AGREEMENTID, A.AGREEMENTNO, A.LESSEEID, A.PRODUCTFLAG, A.APP_FORMNO, A.AMTFIN
FROM LEA_AGREEMENT_DTL A
WHERE A.STATUS = ''A''
AND EXISTS (
  SELECT /*+INDEX(C CR_DECISION_M_CD1)*/ NULL 
  FROM CR_DECISION_M C
  WHERE C.APPID = A.AGREEMENTID
  AND TRUNC(C.AUTHDATE) BETWEEN '''||P_FROM_DATE||''' AND '''||P_TO_DATE||'''
)';
```

Comment: CR_DECISION_M_CD1 has thses two colums : 'APPID', 'TRUNC(AUTHDATE)'

Comment: The code you shared using bind variables, would it improve performance?

Comment: I have tried using bind variable its getting error like bind variables are not allowed in DDL statements. Please suggest.

Comment: Tried code Is like below :

DECLARE
P_FROM_DATE date :=to_date('07/02/2018','mm/dd/yyyy');
P_TO_DATE date :=to_date('07/02/2018','mm/dd/yyyy');
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE C1_LAN_GTT_1 NOLOGGING PARALLEL 4 AS 
  SELECT /*+INDEX(C,CR_DECISION_M_CD1)*/ A.AGREEMENTID, 
  A.AGREEMENTNO, A.LESSEEID, A.PRODUCTFLAG, A.APP_FORMNO, A.AMTFIN
  FROM LEA_AGREEMENT_DTL A, finnlea_bfprod.CR_DECISION_M C
 WHERE A.AGREEMENTID = C.APPID
 AND A.STATUS = ''A''
 AND TRUNC(C.AUTHDATE) BETWEEN :p_from_date AND :p_to_date'
 USING P_FROM_DATE, P_TO_DATE;
END;

Comment: Mutturaj is correct - you can't use bind variables for DDL (and I can't see how it would improve performance anyway if you could).

Comment: @Mutturaj: Sorry, my bad. Cannot use bind variables in DDL. My suggestion is to use exists instead of join between the two tables, it may yield better performance. Though since I do not know the number of records you are dealing with, you should run an explain plan on the join version versus the exists version

Comment: @alexs: Ok Thanks, I will try and let you know soon.